# Why isn't newly selected option sent to server when form is submitted?

Tags: forms, ruby-on-rails-3, html-select

I have a select tag that is built like this:

```
<%= f.select(:id, category_options, include_blank:true) %>
```

The form displays fine and the appropriate model item's option tag is selected.  However, when the user selects a different option and submits the form, the new option is not passed to the server.  Instead, the originally selected value is passed to the server.

The rails log shows the old values being submitted, not the new ones.  The values for this input appear to be cached.This happens in development and production, and in development cache_classes = false.

The rails log like this:

Started PUT "/posts/1999" for 127.0.0.1 at 2012-09-11 13:42:51 -0400
  Processing by GalleriesController#update as HTML

Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"...", "gallery"=>{"publish_on"=>"2012-09-18", "poster_file_temp"=>"", "thumb_file_temp"=>"", "models_attributes"=>{"0"=>{"id"=>"116", "_destroy"=>"false"}, "1"=>{"id"=>"6409", "_destroy"=>"false"}}, "categories_attributes"=>{"0"=>{"id"=>"59", "_destroy"=>"false"}}, "thumb_zip_input"=>"", "medium_zip_input"=>"", "large_zip_input"=>"", "website_url"=>"", "commit"=>"Upload", "id"=>"1999"}

The form looks like this:

```
        <form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="/galleries/1999" class="edit_gallery" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="edit_gallery_1999" method="post" name="edit_gallery_1999">
        <div style="margin:0;padding:0;display:inline">
            <input name="utf8" type="hidden" value="✓"><input name="_method" type="hidden" value="put"><input name="authenticity_token" type="hidden" value="...">
        </div>
        <div class="vert">
            <label for="gallery_publish_on">Publish on</label> <input id="gallery_publish_on" name="gallery[publish_on]" size="30" type="text" value="2012-09-18"> <label for="gallery_poster_file">Poster file</label> <input id="gallery_poster_file_temp" name="gallery[poster_file_temp]" type="hidden"><input id="gallery_poster_file" name="gallery[poster_file]" size="30" type="file">
            <div class='formSection'>
                <img alt="Brandy" src="/content/gallery/poster_file/0000/1999/brandy.jpg">
            </div><label for="gallery_thumb_file">Thumb file</label> <input id="gallery_thumb_file_temp" name="gallery[thumb_file_temp]" type="hidden"><input id="gallery_thumb_file" name="gallery[thumb_file]" size="30" type="file">
            <div class='formSection'>
                <img alt="Thumb" src="/content/gallery/thumb_file/0000/1999/thumb.jpg">
            </div>
            <div id="models">
                <label for="Models">Models</label>
                <div>
                    <select id="gallery_models_attributes_0_id" name="gallery[models_attributes][0][id]">
                        <option value="6409">
                            April
                        </option>
                        <option value="6366" selected="selected">
                            Brandy
                        </option>
                        <option value="9036">
                            Charlie
                        </option>
                        <option value="7490">
                            Craig
                        </option>
                        <option value="9881">
                            Donna
                        </option>
                    </select> <input id="gallery_models_attributes_0__destroy" name="gallery[models_attributes][0][_destroy]" type="hidden" value="false"> <a href="#" class="remove_fields">remove</a>
                </div><input id="gallery_models_attributes_0_id" name="gallery[models_attributes][0][id]" type="hidden" value="6366"> <a href="#" class="add_fields" data-fields="&lt;div&gt; &lt;select id=&quot;gallery_models_attributes_70106238269060_id&quot; name=&quot;gallery[models_attributes][70106238269060][id]&quot;&gt;&lt;option value=&quot;&quot;&gt;&lt;/option&gt;&lt;option value=&quot;6409&quot;&gt;April&lt;/option&gt;&lt;option value=&quot;6366&quot;&gt;Brandy&lt;/option&gt;&lt;option value=&quot;9036&quot;&gt;Charlie&lt;/option&gt;&lt;option value=&quot;7490&quot;&gt;Craig&lt;/option&gt;&lt;option value=&quot;9881&quot;&gt;Donna&lt;/option&gt;&lt;/select&gt; &lt;input id=&quot;gallery_models_attributes_70106238269060__destroy&quot; name=&quot;gallery[models_attributes][70106238269060][_destroy]&quot; type=&quot;hidden&quot; value=&quot;false&quot; /&gt; &lt;a href=&quot;#&quot; class=&quot;remove_fields&quot;&gt;remove&lt;/a&gt;&lt;/div&gt;" data-id="70106238269060">add model</a>
            </div>
            <div id="categories">
                <label for="Categories">Categories</label>
                <div>
                    <select id="gallery_categories_attributes_0_id" name="gallery[categories_attributes][0][id]">
                        <option value="1">
                            Amateur
                        </option>
                        <option value="2">
                            Animals
                        </option>
                        <option value="49">
                            Articles
                        </option>
                        <option value="3">
                            Art
                        </option>
                        <option value="7">
                            Blog
                        </option>
                    </select> <input id="gallery_categories_attributes_0__destroy" name="gallery[categories_attributes][0][_destroy]" type="hidden" value="false"> <a href="#" class="remove_fields">remove</a>
                </div><input id="gallery_categories_attributes_0_id" name="gallery[categories_attributes][0][id]" type="hidden" value="59"> <a href="#" class="add_fields" data-fields="&lt;div&gt; &lt;select id=&quot;gallery_categories_attributes_70106278052860_id&quot; name=&quot;gallery[categories_attributes][70106278052860][id]&quot;&gt;&lt;option value=&quot;&quot;&gt;&lt;/option&gt;&lt;option value=&quot;1&quot;&gt;Amateur&lt;/option&gt;&lt;option value=&quot;2&quot;&gt;Animal&lt;/option&gt;&lt;option value=&quot;49&quot;&gt;Articles&lt;/option&gt;&lt;option value=&quot;3&quot;&gt;Art&lt;/option&gt;&lt;option value=&quot;7&quot;&gt;Blog&lt;/option&gt;&lt;/select&gt; &lt;input id=&quot;gallery_categories_attributes_70106278052860__destroy&quot; name=&quot;gallery[categories_attributes][70106278052860][_destroy]&quot; type=&quot;hidden&quot; value=&quot;false&quot; /&gt; &lt;a href=&quot;#&quot; class=&quot;remove_fields&quot;&gt;remove&lt;/a&gt;&lt;/div&gt;" data-id="70106278052860">add category</a>
            </div>
            <div id='photoset_files'>
                <fieldset>
                    <legend>Zip Files</legend> <label for="gallery_thumb_zip_input">thumb zip</label> <select id="gallery_thumb_zip_input" name="gallery[thumb_zip_input]">
                        <option value="/Library/WebServer/Documents/uploads/thumb copy.zip">
                            thumb copy.zip
                        </option>
                        <option value="/Library/WebServer/Documents/uploads/thumb.zip">
                            thumb.zip
                        </option>
                    </select>&nbsp;[ thumb.zip ]<br>
                    <label for="gallery_medium_zip_input">medium zip</label> <select id="gallery_medium_zip_input" name="gallery[medium_zip_input]">
                        <option value="/Library/WebServer/Documents/uploads/medium copy 10.zip">
                            medium copy 10.zip
                        </option>
                        <option value="/Library/WebServer/Documents/uploads/medium copy 9.zip">
                            medium copy 9.zip
                        </option>
                        <option value="/Library/WebServer/Documents/uploads/medium copy.zip">
                            medium copy.zip
                        </option>
                        <option value="/Library/WebServer/Documents/uploads/medium.zip">
                            medium.zip
                        </option>
                    </select>&nbsp;[ medium.zip ]<br>
                    <label for="gallery_large_zip_input">large zip</label> <select id="gallery_large_zip_input" name="gallery[large_zip_input]">
                        <option value="/Library/WebServer/Documents/uploads/large copy 10.zip">
                            large copy 10.zip
                        </option>
                        <option value="/Library/WebServer/Documents/uploads/large copy 9.zip">
                            large copy 9.zip
                        </option>
                        <option value="/Library/WebServer/Documents/uploads/large copy.zip">
                            large copy.zip
                        </option>
                        <option value="/Library/WebServer/Documents/uploads/large.zip">
                            large.zip
                        </option>
                    </select>&nbsp;[ large.zip ]<br>
                </fieldset>
            </div><label for="gallery_website_url">Website url</label> <input class="wider" id="gallery_website_url" name="gallery[website_url]" size="30" type="text" value=""> <input id="tluo" name="tluo" type="hidden" value="aHR0cDovL2tmLmRldi9nYWxsZXJpZXMvbGlzdA==">
            <div id="submit">
                <input data-disable-with="Uploading..." name="commit" type="submit" value="Upload"> &nbsp;&nbsp; <a href="/galleries/">Cancel</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
```

Comment: can you pls list the total form contents?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because you are repeating the id and name attribute of select . This is not recommended to have two html elements with same id values

try to change name of select or if you want to use this as array then specifying name this way may help you out

```
 gallery[categories_attributes][0][id][]
```

This one I used to collect checked radio button values, it may work in your case

Comment: Thanks very much.  I'm using the select helper to create selects for nested models and it adds a hidden field with the same name and id as the select.  My ugly workaround: I set the value of the hidden field to the value of the select when the select changes.